# JSON, PHP & SQL implementation error

Tags: php, jquery, sql-server, json

I'm trying to work out how to use JSON, php and SQL (initially MSSQL) to populate a type-ahead field of names and, once the name is selected, to also populate a job title and department.  This is my first time to use JSON, so I'm starting a bit from scratch here.

I got a partial solution from Experts Exchange ([see Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fjpsv8u3/)) using static data, but I'm having trouble converting the data I'm pulling from the database to what is being shown in the fiddle.

The code for the fiddle is:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Autocomplete Textbox Demo | PHP | jQuery</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var availableTags = [{
                    empName: "A1",
                    empTitle: "AAA1 AAAAA"
                }, {
                    empName: "A2",
                    empTitle: "AAA2 AAAAA"
                }, {
                    empName: "B",
                    empTitle: "AAA AAAAA"
                }, {
                    empName: "C",
                    empTitle: "AAA AAAAA"
                }];

                var empNames = [];
                var empTitles = [];

                $(availableTags).each(function(ix, v) {
                    empNames.push(v.empName);
                    empTitles.push(v.empTitle);
                });

                $("#empName").autocomplete({
                    source: empNames,
                    autoFocus: true,
                    select: function(event, ui) {
                        //console.log(event);
                        //console.log(ui);
                        //console.log(getTitle(ui.item.label));
                        $("#empTitle").val(getTitle(ui.item.label));
                    }
                });
                $("#empTitle").autocomplete({
                    source: empTitles,
                    autoFocus: true,
                    select: function(event, ui) {
                        //console.log(event);
                        //console.log(ui);
                        //console.log(getName(ui.item.label));
                        $("#empName").val(getName(ui.item.label));
                    }
                });

                function getName(t) {
                    //console.log("title:" + t);
                    for (k in availableTags)
                        if (availableTags[k].empTitle == t) return availableTags[k].empName;
                };

                function getTitle(n) {
                    //console.log("name:" + n);
                    for (k in availableTags) {
                        //console.log("k:" + availableTags[k].empName + " > " + availableTags[k].empTitle);
                        if (availableTags[k].empName == n) return availableTags[k].empTitle;
                    }
                };

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label>Department Name</label></br>
        <input id="empName" type="text" size="50" /><br>
        <input id="empTitle" type="text" size="50" />
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm stuck now on implementing the results returned from the database query to work with the fiddle.  I believe I've to the data correctly formatted but it's wrong somewhere and I'm not sure where that is.

I'm getting the data from an SQL table with a separate php page called `fetchEmpName.php`:-

```
<?php
    require('i_PDOConnection.php');
    $query = "SELECT empFName + ' ' + empLName as [empName], empTitle, empDept FROM tbl_CouncilStaff WHERE active = 1 AND display = 1 AND (empFName LIKE '%".$search."%' OR empLName LIKE '%".$search."%') ORDER BY empLName";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $return_arr = array();
    $return_arr['contacts'] = array();
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $dataArray['empName'] = $row['empName'];
        $dataArray['empTitle'] = $row['empTitle'];
        array_push($return_arr['contacts'],$dataArray);
    }
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

Which (according to the Chrome console log, produces an array like:

```
{empName: "Bob Smith", empTitle: "Chief Cook and Bottle Washer"}
```

Which works properly when I replace the fiddle data with the generated data but fails once the static data is replaced by the sql code.  So that tells me that the problem lies in the script.  At this point, the page has morphed into:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Autocomplete Textbox Demo | PHP | jQuery</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var availableTags = <?php include('fetchEmpName2.php'); ?>;
                var empNames = [];
                var empTitles = [];

                $(availableTags).each(function(x, y) {
                    empNames.push(y.empName);
                    empTitles.push(y.empTitle);
                });
                $("#empName").autocomplete({
                    source: empNames,
                    autoFocus: true,
                    select: function(event, ui) {
                        // console.log(event);
                        // console.log(ui);
                        // console.log(getTitle(ui.item.label));
                        $("#empTitle").val(getTitle(ui.item.label));
                    }
                });
                $("#empTitle").autocomplete({
                    source: empTitles,
                    autoFocus: true,
                    select: function(event, ui) {
                        //console.log(event);
                        //console.log(ui);
                        //console.log(getName(ui.item.label));
                        $("#empName").val(getName(ui.item.label));
                    }
                });
                function getName(t) {
                    //console.log("title:" + t);
                    for (k in availableTags)
                        if (availableTags[k].empTitle == t) return availableTags[k].empName;
                };

                function getTitle(n) {
                    //console.log("name:" + n);
                    for (k in availableTags) {
                        //console.log("k:" + availableTags[k].empName + " > " + availableTags[k].empTitle);
                        if (availableTags[k].empName == n) return availableTags[k].empTitle;
                    }
                };
                console.log(availableTags);
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<label>Department Name</label></br>
<input id="empName" type="text" size="50" /><br>
<input id="empTitle" type="text" size="50" />
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the page, the jquery library throws an error saying

> jquery-ui.min.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined"

I hope this is enough for someone to sort out where I'm off track - or if there is a better way to solving the problem of filling additional fields from a type-ahead field.

Thanks in advance - any assistance offered would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: should be  `ui.item.empTitle`  as you have field name `empTitle`

Comment: Sorry - that didn't change anything - till getting the same error.  In fact with all lines removed I still get that error.

Comment: I've been able to figure out a bit more about this.  I've modified the static version of the page so that it works fine.  It fails once I go to dynamic data though and the only difference I can see is a comma.  I can take the data from the Chrome console and paste it on the page and it fails with the label error.  However, if I add commas between the arrays, it works fine.  So the question becomes how can I add commas between the records or how to modify the script so it does not need the commas.  I could just as easily be all wet in my supposition too.